# What might be wrong with sort by name?

Tags: category, ce-1.9.1.0, sorting

I have set the category products sorting by default to sort by name...

although, if you [check here](https://www.blinckstar.nl/super-sale/bracelets/), that is not working properly.

Already first two items are supposed to show up later in the list.

What could cause this and is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 2 products have a space at the start of the name. it's ' 1401A10 COTTON CANDY' and I assume it should be '1401A10 COTTON CANDY'

Comment: wow that's very sharp :-) i looked many times to find something but i must have been blind ;-)